# How can I search for specific text in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file that has 26 columns. I am trying to find certain text so I can get information I need. The two columns are 'Last Name', 'First Name'.

I found this code on here but I am not getting what I need.

```
dframe['First Name'].where(dframe['Last Name']="James","Turner")
```

I get an error:
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

So then I tried just the first name:

```
dframe['Last Name']=="Turner"
```

I get Boolean of False for the 659.000 rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dframe['Last Name'] == 'Turner'
```

The line above produces a `pandas.Series` of boolean items, that represent whether or not each entry in the `'Last Name'` column matches `'Turner'`

You can use that `pandas.Series` of boolean items to index your dataframe:

```
dframe[dframe['Last Name'] == 'Turner']
```

That should leave you with your desired selection of rows.

Now, if you only wish to look at the `'First Name'` for the selected rows, you can do

```
dframe[dframe['Last Name'] == 'Turner']['First Name']
```

If you want to do a compound search for both first name and last name, you need to perform a bitwise boolean operation between results of individual searches:

```
dframe[(dframe['First Name'] == 'John') & (dframe['Last Name'] == 'Turner')]
```

Finally, to give you a little bonus, if you wish to find all last names that contain `'Turner'`, say something like `'Turner-Jones'`, you can do the following:

```
dframe[dframe['Last Name'].str.contains('Turner')]
```

In the line above you are using the `.str` accessor on the `pandas.Series`, which gives you access to a set of very convenient string methods.  You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#working-with-text-data).

Below I show a working example from an IPython session:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: first_names = ['John', 'Tom', 'Fred', 'Michael', 'Andrew']

In [4]: last_names = ['Turner', 'Harden', 'Bryant', 'Davis', 'Turner']

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(first_names, last_names)), columns=['First Na
me', 'Last Name'])

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
  First Name Last Name
0       John    Turner
1        Tom    Harden
2       Fred    Bryant
3    Michael     Davis
4     Andrew    Turner

In [7]: df[df['Last Name'] == 'Turner']
Out[7]:
  First Name Last Name
0       John    Turner
4     Andrew    Turner

In [8]: df[(df['First Name'] == 'John') & (df['Last Name'] == 'Turner')]
Out[8]:
  First Name Last Name
0       John    Turner

In [9]: df[df['Last Name'].str.contains('r')]
Out[9]:
  First Name Last Name
0       John    Turner
1        Tom    Harden
2       Fred    Bryant
4     Andrew    Turner

In [10]: (df['Last Name'] == 'Turner').any()
Out[10]: True
```

Notice that in the input labeled `In[10]` I went ahead and verified if there were any matches by calling the `any()` method on the boolean `pandas.Series`.  This can be a helpful way of debugging your search if you are having issues getting the results you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am not getting errors now but I am getting just the headers printing out. It shows 0 rows x 36 columns. So I picked a name that I know is in there and it still shows just the headers.

Comment: Hi, I just elaborated on the answer a bit and included a full example that may help clarify your issues.

Comment: Thank you. I did your example and everything works perfectly. But not on my list. My list is a boat registration list of 659,000 rows and 36 columns. Whenever I do a search on last name I only get the headers. Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am still working on it.

Comment: If you are able to post the results of dframe.head() and dframe.dtypes somewhere online I might be able to help you

Comment: Excellent. Maybe this will help. The dataset is from data.texas.gov. Just click on raw data and I downloaded Boat_Owners_with_Current_Registration.csv.  I downloaded just the straight CSV file. So I run dframe = pd.read_csv('Boat_Owners_with_Current_Registration.csv') I get it to print. Then I did dframe[dframe['Last Name'] == 'Bishop'] and that is when I just get the print out of the all the headers but no rows.

Comment: Looks like the 'Last Name' column comes in all caps in that data.  So I would go ahead and try  dframe[dframe['Last Name'] == 'BISHOP'].   If that  works, you might consider marking my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use .isin() like below.

```
dframe[dframe['Last Name'].isin(['James', 'Turner'])]
```

***pandas.DataFrame.isin*** Return boolean DataFrame showing whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values. (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: Good morning thank you for your help. I put in what you gave me using Bishop as the last name and James as the first name because my first row shows this name. But when I run it I just get: 0 rows X 36 columns. It shows me the headers.